# TrueBasic Error: Library LEVEL1.TRU: no such file

Tags: runtime-error, basic

I programmed a game in truebasic and the main program has to call an external library named "LEVEL1.TRU". The main program and LEVEL1.TRU are in the same folder, but for some reason I get the following error:

TrueBasic Error: Library LEVEL1.TRU: no such file

This is in version 6, on a previous version at my school no such error arises.
I'm terribly confused on why this is happening any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so so so so much in advance (:

Answer (score 0):

If you copied and pasted your code here it might help find a typo which is usually the cause of problems like this... Otherwise, try putting the whole file path in...